# Reset index of grouped data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reset the index of grouped data frames and based on the examples, I have written:

```
for name, df_group in df.groupby('BL', as_index=False):
    print(df_group)
```

But the output shows that index has not been reset.

```
      Num               BL  Home  Requester
4   16986  140080043863936     5          5
5   16987  140080043863936     0          5
10  16986  140080043863936     7          5
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: The index is removed after the loop not during the loop. In the loop you have a slice of your original dataframe. And it's valid only when you use `apply`, `agg`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_index=False` does not mean to give 0, 1, ... N index result at the end; it means not to put the grouper(s) to the index but in columns, i.e., "BL" in your case. You can explicitly reset index in the loop:

```py
for name, df_group in df.groupby("BL"):
    print(df_group.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `as_index=False` option of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is useful for groupby methods (it prevents the grouper to become the new index and keeps it as a column), not when looping over the groups manually.

You have to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) here:

```
for name, df_group in df.groupby('BL'):
    print(df_group.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try:

```
print(df_group.reset_index(drop=True))
```